# How to unblock account?

Tags: discussion

I have been blocked from asking questions. I've gone back and answered my own questions. My goal for joining this community was to develop relationships with other members, ask questions, and learn. I would like to be able to pursue my goal to acquire knowledge and experience. Is there something wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

The best available information I could find on this is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/347908).  Basically the ban is automatic, and outside of moderator control.

I just took a look at some of your questions, and it appears they are largely about Math and or Statistics, not really Data Science per se.  Some others were quite broad, and were closed as such.